# Java program runs segmentation fault

Tags: java, shell, segmentation-fault

I have a shell script which is calling my Java program with `xmin` and `xmax` values set. Program is ending fine with exit code 0 /reaching till the end.

But I am getting `Memory Fault` (coredump) when shellscript executes and a core file gets generated.

How to debug to find where the memory leak is and how to fix it?

**Edit:** I am calling my script like

```
Java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m myjava
```

Unix is throwing 267 error.

Comment: kindly share the code.

Comment: You can analyze memory dump with MAT.

Comment: Anyways to debug,of any object is opened .Does local variable needs to be closed?I don't think so what you suggest.

Comment: Code is lengthy,can't really paste it,it's on my linux machine

Comment: Cut out about half of the program and see if the problem persists. If it does, it’s in the remaining half, if it doesn’t, it’s in the half you cut out. Repeat until you have narrowed down the line that has the problem.

Comment: Java -Xms1024m  -Xmx2048m myjava  .this is how I am calling in my script.Unix is throwing 267 error

Comment: Do you have a memory leak or a segmentation fault, and how do you know?